# Backbone.js View Click event selector syntax?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to add an event to my backbone view I have setup.  I want to bind the event to an div in the element of view but I want to select that div by two classes.

Example:

```
<div id="mainContent">
     <div class="small docs"></div>
</div>


        Views.Main = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $("#mainContent"),

            events: {
                "click .small .docs": "renderActiveDocs"

            },

                        initialize: function () {...}
                });
```

Having it set up this way doesn't seem to fire that click.  If I remove either of the classes and just leave one, then it works.

However the class of this div will change from "small" to "large" and I don't want the click event to fire in that case.

Am I missing something in the syntax or is this not possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`click .small.docs`

No space between the two classes.

Reference: second example here: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: sorry had to wait the 10 mins.

Comment: What about pseudo-selectors? Any support? e.g. "click :not(.active) a" for <a>'s that are not inside an ".active" element